# What causes a Netbeans project name to appear in bold?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I made two similar Python projects in Netbeans 6.9.1, and one of them appears in bold.  What causes a Netbeans project name to appear in bold?  None of my other project names are in bold.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"handbrake melissa02" is currently your main project.
see http://wiki.netbeans.org/MainProjectConceptualChange

Answer (score 2):

I have used Netbeans for Java, which in that case, that meant that the project whose name was in bold wass the default project, that is, the project that gets executed when you press the Run (the Green triangle shaped button). I would assume that the same applies here.